# Can I set the DefaultValue to Color.Empty?

Tags: c#

The following always generates an explicit property assignment in my Designer.cs file:

```
[Category("Appearance"), DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Empty")]
public Color PropertyBackColor
{
    get { return propertyBackColor; }
    set { propertyBackColor = value; }
}

Color propertyBackColor = Color.Empty;
```

I get this in my Designer.cs file as if the designer isn't understanding the DefaultValue.

```
this.textBox2.PropertyBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
```

It works fine for any actual color. Just doesn't work for Color.Empty.

Comment: What doesn't work? Exception? IIRC textboxes doesn't support transparent color. I guess empty color also falls in transaparent..

Comment: The designer shouldn't be initializing the property to it's default value in the Designer.cs file.

Comment: Try using `""` instead of `"Empty"` - if it works I'll explain why :)

Comment: Assuming WinForms, Empty isn't a color that shows up in the Designer list of available colors, so try Transparent instead.

Comment: @D Stanley, it does work. Beauty.

Answer (score -1):

Default value can be defined by the ShouldSerialize method. See [Defining Default Values with the ShouldSerialize and Reset Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Sample code as example for this case (adapted from [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) above)

```
    [Category("Appearance")]
    public Color PropertyBackColor
    {
        get { return propertyBackColor; }
        set { propertyBackColor = value; }
    }

    Color propertyBackColor = Color.Empty;

    public bool ShouldSerializePropertyBackColor()
    {
        return propertyBackColor != Color.Empty;
    }
    public void ResetPropertyBackColor()
    {
        propertyBackColor = Color.Empty;
    }
```

I think, methods ShouldSerialize and Reset can be private or protected.